# Extract JSON field from JSON data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

Hi I have a JSON string named `body` with following contents:

`[ { _index: 'domain',
    _type: 'tweets',
    _id: 'AVQDcXJkNcXkyWvNoI-S',
    _score: 1.3844389,
    _source:
     { username: 'rosscmary@gmail.com',
       text: '@amrightnow Go Trump Go Trump Go Trump',
       location: [Object] } },
  { _index: 'domain',
    _type: 'tweets',
    _id: 'AVQDe5CONcXkyWvNoI_G',
    _score: 0.98909086,
    _source:
     { username: 'Trump Hotels Jobs',
       text: '#Vancouver, BC #CustomerService #Job: Reservations Agent at Trump ',
       location: [Object] } },
  { _index: 'domain',
    _type: 'tweets',
    _id: 'AVQDfDpfNcXkyWvNoI_L',
    _score: 0.5487978,
    _source:
     { username: '☩Chaunce☩',
       text: 'While figuring out what 2 do next,  #Trump complains 2 his rep about not winning a "popcorn" it seems he\'ll go after the #MTVMovieAwards too',
       location: [Object] } } ]`

*I want to extract every `text` field from this file and log it to the console.*

*Right now I am doing this :*

`var jsonContent = JSON.parse(body);
    jsonContent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonContent));
    console.log(jsonContent);`

But it's not working.

Can any body help me with this ? I am using node js and been stuck on this one.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string. JSON requires each key to be double-quoted. (i.e. `{ foo: "bar" }` bad, `{ "foo": "bar" }` good).

Comment: okay. So any work around ?

Comment: Good: fix your JSON file. Bad: `var jsonContent = eval(body)`. (But `location: [Object]` will probably not do what you want...)

Comment: Are you sure that JSON is a string? To me it looks like something coming out of console.log

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: Using an editor. (Make a valid JSON file.) There is no way for us to know what `location` should be, for example.

Comment: Ahh.. I got this content from Amazon elastic search query.

Answer (score 1):

Here a complete solution if you start with your object in json string format

```js
var jsonString = "[{\"_index\":\"domain\",\"_type\":\"tweets\",\"_id\":\"AVQDcXJkNcXkyWvNoI-S\",\"_score\":1.3844389,\"_source\":{\"username\":\"rosscmary@gmail.com\",\"text\":\"@amrightnow Go Trump Go Trump Go Trump\",\"location\":[null]}},{\"_index\":\"domain\",\"_type\":\"tweets\",\"_id\":\"AVQDe5CONcXkyWvNoI_G\",\"_score\":0.98909086,\"_source\":{\"username\":\"Trump Hotels Jobs\",\"text\":\"#Vancouver, BC #CustomerService #Job: Reservations Agent at Trump \",\"location\":[null]}},{\"_index\":\"domain\",\"_type\":\"tweets\",\"_id\":\"AVQDfDpfNcXkyWvNoI_L\",\"_score\":0.5487978,\"_source\":{\"username\":\"☩Chaunce☩\",\"text\":\"While figuring out what 2 do next, #Trump complains 2 his rep about not winning a \\\"popcorn\\\" it seems he'll go after the #MTVMovieAwards too\",\"location\":[null]}}]";

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

jsonObj.map((elt) => {
  console.log(elt["_source"].text);
});
```